# Which database stores sys.tables or sys.indexes in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, system-views

I am not able to figure out where these system tables are stored, your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does it matter? What if you figure it out and the vendor changes its location in the next release.

Answer (score 4):

These are views.

The view definitions are held in the hidden [resource database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/resource-database?view=sql-server-2017) but they access [system base tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/system-base-tables?view=sql-server-2017) held in each individual database.

You can use `sp_helptext` to see the definition of `sys.indexes` (and that it accesses `sys.sysidxstats`, `sys.syssingleobjrefs`, `sys.syspalvalues`) but attempting this with `sys.objects` just shows a `SELECT` against `sys.objects$`.

If you view the execution plan for a select against `sys.objects` you can see the objects accessed however.

```
  |--Hash Match(Right Outer Join, HASH:([n].[value])=([o].[type]), RESIDUAL:([mssqlsystemresource].[sys].[syspalnames].[value] as [n].[value]=[foo].[sys].[sysschobjs].[type] as [o].[type]))
       |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([mssqlsystemresource].[sys].[syspalnames].[cl] AS [n]), SEEK:([n].[class]='OBTY') ORDERED FORWARD)
       |--Hash Match(Right Outer Join, HASH:([r].[depid])=([o].[id]))
            |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([foo].[sys].[syssingleobjrefs].[nc1] AS [r]),  WHERE:([foo].[sys].[syssingleobjrefs].[class] as [r].[class]=(97) AND [foo].[sys].[syssingleobjrefs].[depsubid] as [r].[depsubid]=(0)))
            |--Filter(WHERE:(has_access('CO',[foo].[sys].[sysschobjs].[id] as [o].[id])=(1)))
                 |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1006]=CONVERT(bit,[foo].[sys].[sysschobjs].[status] as [o].[status]&(1),0), [Expr1009]=CONVERT(bit,[foo].[sys].[sysschobjs].[status] as [o].[status]&(16),0), [Expr1010]=CONVERT(bit,[foo].[sys].[sysschobjs].[status] as [o].[status]&(64),0)))
                      |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([foo].[sys].[sysschobjs].[clst] AS [o]), WHERE:([foo].[sys].[sysschobjs].[nsclass] as [o].[nsclass]=(0) AND [foo].[sys].[sysschobjs].[pclass] as [o].[pclass]=(1)))
```

But the system base tables cannot be queried directly except via the DAC so this information is only rarely useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

All sys objects are stored in resource database and are logically visible under sys schema of each database.

Example :

`Select * from Database.sys.sysaltfiles` will give you results despite this view not in that database.

Comment: Your answer is not an improvement over Martin's answer.